How to compose a server component as a child to Group without extra markup?
Generally, I should be able to, and can compose a server component as a child to a client component.
But with Mantine's various layout-focused components, when I try, for example, to nest my server component inside a <Group> for layout purposes, like this:
const ProjectsListPage = async () => {
  return (
    <Group>
      <ProjectsList /> //  <-- a server component
    </Group>
  );
};

... I get this problem:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, _payload, _init}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Note: ProjectsList at its outermost layer resolves to a single div, via Mantine's Box component, so the "collection of children" part of the error message is extra confusing.
This error goes away if I simply nest the server component within a div:
const ProjectsListPage = async () => {
  return (
    <Group>
      <div> //  <-- extra div fixes it. Why?
        <ProjectsList /> 
      </div>
    </Group>
  );
};

...but the problem re-appears if I replace the div with a fragment, which is ... quite frustrating because that's how we usually address this type of error message w/o extra markup. The trick also does NOT work if I make a dedicated wrapper component for Group with a div surrounding it -- it has to be there as a direct child to the Group in composition within the outer server component, as descendent in the page. This seems really bizarre and I don't understand why this is.
Can anyone either explain why this is, and/or provide a better fix that does not require an extra layer of markup?
